# Integer arguments(%1$d) supplied to context.getString(resource_id) gets translated in some languages

Tags: android, internationalization, android-resources

In some languages(for eg. Burmese in my case), the integer format arguments(supplied to getString() for localized string) also get translated. How to avoid this? Thanks

Attached images in english and burmese(For string: **Sample size: %1$d**)

In English:

[image: English]

In Burmese:

[image: Burmese]

Code for the scenario:

```
class Main2Activity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        textView3.text = getString(R.string.sample_size_text, 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: please post your code, although I actually do understand your question

Comment: integer argument supplied with %1$d is not proper, it should be "2"(and not J) in Burmese also, right?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, what code you mean? getString(R.string.sample_size_text, 2) ?

Comment: yes, just add how you're calling it so others can see

Comment: add a complete code example of your issue is what i'm saying

Comment: @a_local_nobody, added test code for the scenario, the layout having only 1 textview

Answer (score 0):

It is not "J", it is "2", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_numerals

Burmese has its own digits, does not use the Western ones.

Comment: In the question, I mentioned, "the integer format arguments(supplied to getString() for localized string) also get translated. How to avoid this?"

Comment: In all other languages the format integer argument doesn't get translated as you would have seen multiple times

Comment: Is there any way to get English numbers in Burmese, as to make it consistent with other languages